# "Search Option" adding Multi-Value properties but wont show up as intended

Tags: search, properties

I added 3 new Property to user profile (thru CA > Manage User Properties). These are Team ID, Team Name, Team Type. Team Name and Type are string Multi Value type field. I have a bdc that should populates these fields everynight. Only ID gets populated (or updated) and rest of the fields are not being populated or updated. I have added these fields in "Search Option" (including name, location,etc fields). (I manually added TeamName and TeamType of the some of the records; Not sure if I need to do incremental crawl in order to show up in the Search Options as multi-value type field or pick-list type). Shouldn't I be seeing a drop down or pick list for TeamName and TeamType in the search option box because they are multi-value type properties. (see "Search Options" image link)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/813/searchoption.jpg/

```
<Properties>   
<Property Name="EmployeeName" ManagedName="EmployeeName" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:EmployeeName"/>   
<Property Name="Location" ManagedName="Location" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:Location"/>   
<Property Name="Department" ManagedName="Department" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:Department"/>   
<Property Name="EmpPhone" ManagedName="EmpPhone" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:EmpPhone"/>   
<Property Name="TeamName" ManagedName="TeamName" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:TeamName"/>
<Property Name="TeamType" ManagedName="TeamType" ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:TeamType"/>
</Properties>
```